# How to design syntax for complex command line options?

Tags: c++, c, command-line, arguments, getopt

Suppose my command line utility can send messages with following structure

```
struct Message {
    uint32_t ip;
    string id;
}
```

User must be able to specify **host**(ipv4+port) and **filters** on ip and id **per host**
(allowed network addresses and ids to send). How can I design
clear syntax for such complex option?

The best what I invented is:

```
--msg-send="192.168.10.2:8080;ip_isin=10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.1/16;id=one,two"
```

But something is wrong with it... for example sign `=` inside is
annoying... Does anybody knows "the silver bullet" for command line arguments with complex structure?

another variant is better:

```
--msg-send="192.168.10.2:8080{ip 10.0.0.0/8,172.168.0.0/16}{id one,two}"
```

**UPD:** msg-send is plural, user can set several hosts with different filters

Comment: @Sumit, does it matter? Yes, I'm using getopt.

Comment: It could help your question. The `c` tag on here is more popular than the tags you used.

Comment: According to Fred Brooks, there is No Silver Bullet. Snarkiness aside, I'd break that command down. If you won't have more than one `--msg-send` I'd spin the filters and ID off into separate arguments

Comment: So you have as many `id`s as you do `ip`s (one for each) but only one `host:port`?

Comment: --dest "192.168.10.2:8080" --filt "one=10.0.0.0/8" --filt "two=172.168.0.0/16" ?

Comment: Do the arguments need to be on the command line? Would it make more sense to give the command a file containing the arguments in some more legible multi-line format?

Comment: @KeithThompson I want to collect as many solutions as possible for exactly option syntax design. It'll be best to sort them by votes.

Answer (score 3):

There's no silver bullet, however, when interacting with humans you should try to follow human way of thinking. You're trying to make the user to compose a complex structure, somewhat resembling JSON format, by hand. Humans are bad at this. From your explanation I get that this structure has three components:

1. host+port
2. list of IPs (identified by subnets, CIDR notations,
   rangers, whatever your program can handle)
3. list of string ids

Thus it might be logical to require the user to enter these parameters separately, for example

```
msg_util.exe --host 192.168.10.2:8080 --allowed_ips 10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.1/16 --allowed_ids one,two
```

If you might have many hosts with corresponding allowed IPs and ids, then it'd be quite awkward to enter it from command line alone, and many network utilities (like [dig](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig)) resort to consume input from files. For example you could have

```
msg_util.exe --file --host hosts_file --allowed_ips ips_file --allowed_ids ids_file
```

where each line of `hosts_file` has corrseponding options in `ips_file` and `ids_file`

Comment: Yes, msg-send is plural. Sorry I didn't mention it in the question - updated.